# why should we include <servlet-name> in deployment descriptor file

Tags: servlets, web.xml

i have tried without giving servlet-name tag in my web.XML but it did not worked for me.

we are adding servlet-class & url tags in deployment descriptor file here what is the exact use of adding  servlet-name tag in deployment descriptor file (web.XML).
Cant we run without servlet-name tag in our web.xml

Comment: How would you map URLs to your servlet if you didn't have servlet-name?

Answer (score 0):

The `<servlet-name>` is a unique identifier for a single `Servlet`. Some deployment descriptor elements some times need to refer to a specific servlet. They do that through the value of the `<servlet-name>`. For example, you might have multiple `<servlet-mapping>` elements, one for each extension. You might also have a `Filter` which you want applied only to a specific servlet.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pack.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.pack.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>   
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```